# Get JSON value from API array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, api

slight JSON issue,
Assuming my endpoint is http://api.quran.com:3000/api/v3/search?q=allah&size=20&page=0&language=en,
how do I access the translations data in the api, I've done this

```
results = data.results;
var li= '';
for (const x of results) {
    li+='<li>'+x.text_madani+' <span class="surah">'+x.verse_key+'</span><span class="surah">'+x.translations.text+'</span></li>';
    console.log(data.results.translations.text)
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = li;
```

I am having issues locating the translations data in the api, If i am correct, would it not be, data.results.translations.text? I want the for loop to display the translations for each arabic after the verse itself is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the index.

`translations` is also an array of objects, in the example below i've used index `0` as an example. You should choose the desired translation

```
results = data.results;
var li= '';
for (const x of results) {
    li+='<li>'+x.text_madani+' <span class="surah">'+x.verse_key+'</span><span class="surah">'+x.translations[0].text+'</span></li>';
    
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = li;
```

Comment: what if I want to display all translations?

Comment: you could loop through all translations similarly to the results

Comment: I dont know how

Comment: I almost never used nested loops